# iTunes Connect Price Change Error: "Price Tier Effective or End Dates in the past are not allowed"

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes-store

So I'm trying to do a one week price drop promotion for one of my paid apps, but I keep getting this error that says "Price Tier Effective or End Dates in the past are not allowed".

I tried all sorts of date ranges & the only one that seems to work is a single price tier from the current date to eternity, even a schedule with two price tiers wouldn't work.

I'm running OSX 10.10.5, tried it on FireFox 41.0 and Safari 8.0.8 (10600.8.9), and still couldn't get it to work.

Apple has updated their dashboard a few days ago & could this be a bug caused by the new update? Has anyone experienced the same issue or found a workaround?

[image: itunes connect error Price Tier Effective or End Dates in the past are not allowed]

Answer (score 22):

It seems a timezone problem. If you change your timezone to some other timezone that is already on the next day, you'll be able to set the times without problem.

So, a temporary fix is to change your timezone to something like New Zealand.

Comment: The problem there is I don't know where can I change time zone :-)

Comment: You don't need to change iTunes Connect's time zone, you just need to change your coumputer's time zone. Your browser will then communicate your timezone back to the server ;)

I had the same problem and this actually worked.

Comment: I changed the timezone to PDT and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Switching to NZ time zone also worked for me. I wonder if this means that when you set a start date and end date for price changes, if starts at midnight worldwide for the timezone you have set?

Comment: Apple really needs to get there stuff together its been over a month with this issue and it hasn't been resolved..

Comment: It had to be exactly PDT for me. CET or NZ's time zone didn't work.

Comment: In Portugal, setting New Zealand's timezone only works after midday.

Comment: I am speechless here.... but you actually have to change the time zone on your Mac in order for it to work.... seriously the worst implementation of iTunes Connect so far!

Comment: Wellcome in AJ, the new time system! It means After Jobs! During the Jobs era these amateurs would have been fired immediately! It's a shame! Anyway PDT worked for me even I supposed these programmers worked in Seattle timeZone.

Comment: Unbelievable. Setting timezone to PST worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The timezone didn't work for me but changing mannualy the date to tomorrow worked.

thanks Apple. i'm glad to pay 99€ per year for this.

Comment: iTunesConnect is buggier than an entomologists collection

Answer (score 1):

Manual set the price tier effective date to forever to solve it temporary. I think Apple need some Tester after made some smart changes.